# deployment issues for phoenix app using gatling and distillery to deploy to a VPS

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, gatling

I'm using the below command on my VPS to deploy an app I recently put together.

```
sudo -E mix gatling.deploy kegcopr_api
```

However, the deployment errors out when it tries to start the app as a service.

```
$ mix release --warnings-as-errors --env=prod (/home/deploy/kegcopr_api)
==> Assembling release..
==> Building release kegcopr_api:0.0.1 using environment prod
==> Including ERTS 8.3 from /home/deploy/.asdf/installs/erlang/19.3/lib/erlang/erts-8.3
==> Packaging release..
==> Release successfully built!
    You can run it in one of the following ways:
      Interactive: _build/prod/rel/kegcopr_api/bin/kegcopr_api console
      Foreground: _build/prod/rel/kegcopr_api/bin/kegcopr_api foreground
      Daemon: _build/prod/rel/kegcopr_api/bin/kegcopr_api start
$ tar -xf kegcopr_api.tar.gz (/home/deploy/deployments/kegcopr_api)
/etc/init.d/kegcopr_api already exists
$ service kegcopr_api start
** (ErlangError) erlang error: :enoent
    (elixir) lib/system.ex:564: System.cmd("service", ["kegcopr_api", "start"], [stderr_to_stdout: true, into: %IO.Stream{device: :standard_io, line_or_bytes: :line, raw: false}])
    lib/gatling/tasks/deploy.ex:189: Mix.Tasks.Gatling.Deploy.start_service/1
    lib/gatling/tasks/deploy.ex:201: Mix.Tasks.Gatling.Deploy.call/2
    lib/gatling/tasks/deploy.ex:39: Mix.Tasks.Gatling.Deploy.deploy/1
    (mix) lib/mix/task.ex:294: Mix.Task.run_task/3
    (mix) lib/mix/cli.ex:58: Mix.CLI.run_task/2
```

Any help related to this issue would greatly be appreciated.

And I forgot to mention I'm using erlang 19.3 and elixir 1.4.2 via the asdf package manager.

**Update**
Removed the file `/etc/init.d/kegcopr_api` and reran the below command,

```
sudo -E mix gatling.deploy kegcopr_api
```

Now I'm getting the following error messages.

```
$ mix release --warnings-as-errors --env=prod (/home/deploy/kegcopr_api)
==> Assembling release..
==> Building release kegcopr_api:0.0.1 using environment prod
==> Including ERTS 8.3 from /home/deploy/.asdf/installs/erlang/19.3/lib/erlang/erts-8.3
==> Packaging release..
==> Release successfully built!
    You can run it in one of the following ways:
      Interactive: _build/prod/rel/kegcopr_api/bin/kegcopr_api console
      Foreground: _build/prod/rel/kegcopr_api/bin/kegcopr_api foreground
      Daemon: _build/prod/rel/kegcopr_api/bin/kegcopr_api start
$ tar -xf kegcopr_api.tar.gz (/home/deploy/deployments/kegcopr_api)
$ update-rc.d kegcopr_api defaults
** (ErlangError) erlang error: :enoent
    (elixir) lib/system.ex:564: System.cmd("update-rc.d", ["kegcopr_api", "defaults"], [stderr_to_stdout: true, into: %IO.Stream{device: :standard_io, line_or_bytes: :line, raw: false}])
    lib/gatling/tasks/deploy.ex:139: Mix.Tasks.Gatling.Deploy.install_init_script/1
    lib/gatling/tasks/deploy.ex:201: Mix.Tasks.Gatling.Deploy.call/2
    lib/gatling/tasks/deploy.ex:37: Mix.Tasks.Gatling.Deploy.deploy/1
    (mix) lib/mix/task.ex:294: Mix.Task.run_task/3
    (mix) lib/mix/cli.ex:58: Mix.CLI.run_task/2
```

Comment: What OS are you running on the VPS?

Comment: @Dogbert I'm running Debian 7.11 on the VPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by setting up a droplet with Digital Ocean that is running Debian 8.7 instead of 7.11.